# Delete duplicate records after combining multiple primary keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have a scenario where there can be multiple types(type1 : xxxxxx, yyyyyy and type 2: aaaaa, bbbbb)  associated for the same num(provided the condition same  user name

I mean there can multiple types for the same user name with same num and p_id
Now I have to combine values 1,2,3,4,5 for pk 1 and pk 2 (fig 1)as they have similar types (type 1 xxxxx and type 2: aaaaa) for both the primary keys

These values have to be combined with max(pk) i.e pk =2 as per fig 1

Then the result set should look as in fig 2.
After combining the values, I have to delete the pk 1 from table name: values, there should be only max(pk) (which is pk =2) as I am combine the values.

Can someone please help me out with this. I would really appreciate your help

```
Pk  num    P_id   year   Value value value  value value  type    type    username
                          1      2     3     4     5     1        2

1  123456  4567   2012    $2     $5     0     0 0    xxxxx   aaaaa     mr.nice
2  123456  4567   2012    $1     $5     $2    0  0    xxxxx   aaaaa     mr.nice
3  123456  4567   2012     0     $2     0     0   0    yyyyy    bbbbb     mr.nice
Fig 1: Table name: values


Pk  num    P_id   year  Value value value  value   value  type   type    username
                          1      2     3     4       5     1      2

2  123456  4567   2012    $3   $10     $2    0   0       xxxxx   aaaaa    mr.nice
3  123456  4567   2012    $0     2      0    0     0       yyyyy   bbbbb    mr.nice
```

Fig 2: Table name: values
result set- after combining the values

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please don't add noise and clutter like `*************` to your questions. It won't get you answers any faster, it distracts from the question you're trying to ask, and it wastes the time of people who have to remove it. It's much better if you spend the time and effort into asking a more specific question (or cleaning up the content of your question instead to make it more readable). Thanks.

Comment: Also, I have no idea what you "Fig 1" and "Fig 2" are trying to convey, because the formatting is unreadable. Please [edit] to try and clean it up so we can tell what it is supposed to represent. (You can click the little orange `?` at the top right of the text area to get formatting help, but at a least code and sample data should be indented by four spaces to mark it as such.) Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Ken!! I tried uploading the image, but it did not allow me since I don't have minimum reputations

Answer (score 0):

you combine values using GROUP BY clause. When you use this clause you need to use aggregate function (like MAX, SUM, etc.). Here is the example you would use for your problem:

```
SELECT MAX(Pk),
    num,
    P_id,
    year,
    SUM(Value1),
    SUM(value2),
    SUM(value3),
    SUM(value4),
    SUM(value5),
    type1,
    type2,
    username
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY 
    num,
    P_id,
    year,
    type1,
    type2,
    username
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using all your fields but you get the point with this example:

@Fig1 is a temp table that roughly resembles what you want to do, we will insert the important values into it.

```
declare @fig1 table  ( PK int, val1 money, val2 money, vtype varchar(5), vtype2 varchar(5)  )
declare @uPK table ( PK int)

insert into @fig1 values
(1, 2, 5, 'xxxxx', 'aaaaa'),
(2, 1, 5, 'xxxxx', 'aaaaa'),
(3, 0, 2, 'yyyyy', 'bbbbb');
```

Here is where the magic begins, we use a common table expression to calculate what the new values of the fields should be, naming that new on the fly table: Updates

```
WITH Updates 
AS (
select 
    max(PK) as PK,
    sum(val1) as Val1,
    sum(val2) as Val2
from @fig1
group by vtype, vtype2)
```

Next we update the values based on this new aggregate table and use our OUTPUT keyword to tell us which values were updated, pushing those values into a temp variable @uPK.

```
Update f
    set val1=U.Val1, val2=U.val2
OUTPUT INSERTED.PK into @uPK
from Updates U 
inner join @fig1 f on U.pk=f.pk;
```

Once we know which ones should stay, we simply remove those that shouldn't be there.  Also, with this delete you likely only want to remove those that match the types of those that were updated, but basic T-SQL will get you down this road.

```
delete f
from @fig1 f
left outer join @uPK p on f.PK=p.PK
where p.PK is null

select * from @fig1
```

Comment: Let me know if it works, with these test tables it works fine, of course you'll need to add your extra fields and change names.

Comment: Feel free to click the up arrow next to the questions to show that it worked for you.